# Wine Close Button On Top Bar

Tags: c, wine

If "Allow windows manager to decorate window" is on.
What is the function name in the wine source that knows a user click this X button and send the WM_CLOSE to the app?
Thank you

Comment: For which window class? They all have their own WindowProc, which in turn calls functions internal to the DLL in which the code resides. What are you actually trying to achieve? This sounds like an X/Y problem, where by you have a problem, X. Thinking Y to be the answer, you ask how to achieve that, yet, if people knew the problem to be X, the answers they'd give would be very different.

Comment: I'm just thinking that there is a function somewhere in wine source ,let's name it XButton() .And when a user click on 'X' on top bar to close the window , this XButton() fucntion is called .But i dnt know the real name of this window

Comment: On top bar is minimize , maximize , and Close ( X) buttons . I need to know what wine function is called when a user Click on X . Winecfg have Allow window manager to control the windows , ON , so the top bar is decorated by linux .Linux adds this top bar , And I just hope linux to call a wine function when user click on X

Comment: http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/user32/defwnd.c#269 http://source.winehq.org/ident?_i=NC_HandleNCLButtonDown http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/user32/defwnd.c#0264 http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/user32/nonclient.c#1308

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window manager sends ClientMessage with type WM_PROTOCOLS and the protocol value WM_DELETE_WINDOW.  This is handled in dlls/winex11.drv/event.c: X11DRV_ClientMessage() -> handle_wm_protocols().